# Some classes returned by objc_getClassList aren't accessible

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, objective-c-runtime

My code is crashing (rarely) while accessing classes retrieved by `objc_getClassList`

Crash message:

> objc[48740]: Attempt to use unknown class 0x600000ac2640.

```
var numClasses: Int32 = 0
var newNumClasses = objc_getClassList(nil, 0)
var classes: UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass>?

while (numClasses < newNumClasses) { // calling objc_getClassList until all returned classes are fitting into the buffer
    numClasses = newNumClasses
    if let classes = classes {
        classes.deallocate()
    }
    classes = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass>.allocate(capacity: Int(numClasses))
    let buffer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyClass>(classes)
    newNumClasses = objc_getClassList(buffer, numClasses);
}

for i in 0..<Int(newNumClasses) {
    let someclass: AnyClass = classes![i]
    let s = "\(someclass)" // crash happens here
    
    // not very costly computations here
}
```

Mostly it happens when iteration is performed for 80% or so. Total number of classes is around 50000. It reproduces more often on slower devices/simulators. No other signs of heap corruption are present. Memory graph is fine.

Classes around the broken one looks somewhat like this: `fir_420DF5A9-4BF1-468C-8919-FFAA7D864314_GDTCCTUploadOperation` (this is a name of the class. Looks firebasy).

EDIT: Alternatively

```
var count: UInt32 = 0
guard let classList = objc_copyClassList(&count) else {
    return []
}
return UnsafeBufferPointer(start: classList, count: Int(count)).filter { (type: AnyClass) in
    return class_conformsToProtocol(type, protocolName)
}
```

Produces the same result (again, very rarely)

Please let me know if anyone has an idea how to filter out dead/inaccessible classes.

Thank you.

Comment: (a) You shouldn't need to call `objc_getClassList` in a loop —the initial call given `nil, 0` will return the actual number of classes registered with the runtime, and on the second call will fill the entirety of the list you hand it, given the correct count; (b) classes registered with the runtime are not guaranteed to be `NSObject`-deriven classes, and may not respond to any meaningful messages, and can crash if you try to access them. What are you trying to actually do with these classes?

Comment: Regarding call in a loop official sources says otherwise: https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-267.1/runtime/objc-runtime.h.auto.html 

I'm looking for custom classes that implements particular protocol. Using `class_conformsToProtocol`

Comment: BTW, objc4-267.1 is positively ancient — check the copyright (2003). The latest available open-source header (https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/runtime.h.auto.html) does not make the same suggestion. Theoretically, you could use the loop to guard against classes being registered between the original call to `objc_getClassList` and subsequent ones, but the risk is vanishingly small. If you're concerned about that, you should just use `objc_copyClassList`, which will give you everything in one go. (But this is completely orthogonal to your question.)

Comment: In any case, if you just check `class_conformsToProtocol` without printing the class (which can trigger a message-send to try to get the class's preferred name) or otherwise interacting with it, what behavior do you get? (Obj-C runtime functions are the _only_ functions safe to use on unknown classes, but they should also always work, unless some memory corruption is going on in-process.)

Comment: While loop runs 2-3 times in some situations. Without the loop crash happens too. I just added it to be sure. (BTW, everything is running on the main thread)

Comment: `class_conformsToProtocol` triggers the exact same error "Attempt to use unknown class 0x600...", so I replaced it in this example with just printing out the class name.
Moreover, `try? class_conformsToProtocol...` doesn't help

Comment: To rule out anything particularly strange with `objc_getClassList`, can you try using `objc_copyClassList` instead and seeing what the results are? Also, if you’ve been seeing the loop making several iterations, which is _highly_ unusual, it seems possible that classes are being dynamically created and destroyed in your process — between when the class list is handed to you, one of the classes could be getting deregistered. (This would be _very_ strange.)

Comment: I would also suggest running this code with the Address Sanitizer active to make sure no memory corruption is actually going on, which is the only other cause I can think of which would lead to the runtime not recognizing the classes it itself is handing to you.

Comment: These class creation/destructions are performed by firebase (as far as I understand). Address sanitizer doesn't prevent this issue (error message doesn't change). `objc_copyClassList` produces same result (I'll update the question). Thank you for suggesting this alternative

Comment: At what point in your app life cycle is this code running? I don't know anything about Firebase, but I would hope that if it's dynamically creating and destroying classes, it would get most if not all of that out of the way very early in startup. If you're trying this code at startup, could you just confirm this may resolve the issue by trying it once things have "quieted down" a bit, so to speak? Though if Firebase does this throughout the lifetime of your app, you may be truly out of luck (I would file a bug report on Firebase for this behavior, if true)

Comment: If you have access to the Firebase SDK (source or binary), you could try searching for `objc_disposeClassPair` to see if they're actually disposing of dynamically-created classes. If so, you basically have a dangling pointer pointing to nothing, which is impossible to recover from.

Comment: It happens 5+ seconds from the launch (up to several minutes), not on the launch. So yes, looks like I'm out of luck. It's cheaper (in terms of development time) to just scrap this whole part and replace it with some other mechanics. You can post it as your solution and I'll mark it as the accepted one. Thank you, really!